# When do we say 'problem' or 'difficulty'; when do we say 'issue'?

Tags: word-choice

My car has a funny knocking sound in the engine, so I telephone the garage. What do I say? 'I have a problem with my car'? or 'I have an issue with my car'?

My neighbour is suffering clinical depression. Is this an 'issue' or an 'illness'?

My computer keeps crashing. I call the support people. Do I say my computer has an issue or that it is not working properly?

The dinner is burning in the oven. Sorry, dear, there is an issue concerning tonight's meal? Right or wrong?

A child is being bullied at school by an older child. Is this a 'pupil relationship issue' or is it 'child abuse'?

My neighbour's dog keeps barking and keeps us awake at night, so eventually I go to the neighborhood mediator. Do I tell him there is an 'issue with the dog', or that the dog is driving us insane?

If there is dog's muck on the recreation ground where children play, is this an 'issue' or a 'disgrace'?

The word 'issue' has become ubiquitous, and things that were once 'problems' and 'difficulties', or needed fixing, are now 'issues'.

Sooner or later I am going to bawl down the phone at someone who says 'I understand there is an issue with a delivery of a parcel to your address'. Yes, there's an issue alright, it hasn't been delivered!

When is a problem a problem, and a fault a fault, a breakdown a breakdown, a failed delivery a failed delivery,  and when is it an 'issue'?

Your ideas please.

Comment: The phantom down-voter has been at work. No doubt they have an 'issue' with what I have written.

Comment: I didn't down vote, but this sounds to me less like a question and more like venting, so I voted to close as POB. By the way, I've seen a question like this before – I'll see if I can dig it up for you.

Comment: @BraddSzonye If you look at the comment I have made under Oldcat's answer, you will see that I fully accept that 'issue' is a legitimate expression. All I am asking is when should it be used? Its use has grown exponentially, doubling in use in the last 38 years. In my view it is used inappropriately, but we need to discuss when it is valid and when not. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=issues&year_start=1970&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cissues%3B%2Cc0

Comment: See also: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/134811/use-of-the-word-issue-as-a-euphemism-for-problem?rq=1

Comment: As interesting as it is, the question asks for opinions and, having read the answers, I agree that they are opinions.

Comment: There is no problem in saying an inanimate object has a problem. A problem with coworkers, however, assigns blame, and thus the problem is only an *issue*. A reasonable euphemism.

Answer (score 2):

It might be best parsed this way....I have an **issue**. You have a **difficulty**. He has a **problem**.

Comment: +1 Valid point. But there are genuine reasons for some things being called 'issues'; the sorts of things that do not lend themselves to easy resolution e.g. the conflict in Syria. Or that of a lady I saw tonight who has MS. This presents a 'mobility issue'. If a child has Asberger's syndrome, this presents lots of 'issues' with which the parents have to deal. But if something is broken which can be mended, that I would term a problem, until it gets fixed.

Comment: An issue in the political sense is a source of contention. They could be discussed and resolved. Wars shouldn't be issues, as you fight them and resolve them that way.  Mobility issues are not really discussable, we call them issues to **avoid** discussing them.

Comment: I don't agree with the idea that *issue / difficulty / problem* are meaningfully related to *first / second / third person pronouns*. With no additional context to distinguish possible shades of meaning, the only difference between them is that idiomatically *all of us, separately and collectively* are far more likely to ***have difficulty*** (without the indefinite article).

Comment: It is a reflection of the old parsing jokes. "I am direct - you are blunt - He is rude" These days 'issue' is the least judgmental and the one least likely to admit of a resolution.  Problems still seem to require action.

Answer (score 1):

The word "issue" always implies contention. A long time ago, female suffrage was not an issue; nobody really thought that women should have the vote.

Then, in the nineteenth and early twentieth centuries, it became an issue; many people campaigned for women's right to vote and many resisted.

Now it is again a non-issue; nobody takes the position that women shouldn't vote.

Slavery was both an issue and a problem in America in the nineteenth century.
It was a problem in the eyes of anti-slavery folk because they saw it as a great social evil that caused terrible suffering.
The pro slavery folk didn't see it as a problem; they saw it as a natural state of affairs that suited them just fine

But both sides regarded it as an issue. It was a matter of contention and debate and, eventually, war.

Now it is neither a problem nor an issue.

The teaching of evolution is still an issue, and some would regard it as a problem.

Strokes are a medical problem; they kill and disable people.
As far as I know they are not an issue. As far as I know there is no significant disagreement about their causation and treatment.

But it makes sense to talk about the cholesterol issue, because some people regard cholesterol  as a great danger while others say it's relatively harmless.

To say "my son has issues at school" when you mean, "my son is both lazy and stupid" shows you like weasel words.

To say "my computer has issues with the motherboard" demonstrates that you have no feel for language at all.

But in the world as it actually exists, very few people care about precision and accuracy in language, so don't worry about it.

Comment: I do not agree with much of what you have written, e.g. people are beginning to use the word 'issue' to mean medical things like strokes. And though I disagree vehemently with the idea behind your final sentence,  will give you a +1 for making the effort to reply.

Answer (score 1):

Quite simply, an issue is a matter of doubt or debate or contentiom. A problem is a difficulty that needs to be solved or resolved. Anyone wishing to use these words clearly and accurately should have no diificulty in doing so if they are aware of their true meanings. Everyone else who have no respect for precision in the use of language should continue to misuse the word "issue".

Answer (score 0):

The use of "issue" for a problem originated with pop psychologists teaching people to BS themselves and was adoped by organizations trying to BS the public. It's a weasel word. If you call a problem a problem, your meaning will always be clear. If you call it an issue, it might not be. I have seen news stories that were unintelligible because "issue" was thrown around too much, and I have sat in meetings in which it was impossible to tell what people meant.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).